# creating four symmetric holes from one along two axis

Tags: modeling

I want to create four symmetric holes from one along two axis. While the object(a box) itself is fully symmetric along the Y axis, but is only partially symmetric along the X-axis, so I can't just use one mirror modifier and select both X and Y axis of symmetry. See the picture:

[image]

What is the proper way to deal with the partial symmetry along the X-axis and create the second symmetrical hole on one side of the box? At the end I want to have this - if I change the original hole - all other 3 holes change itself automatically.

Comment: add a bolean with the difference object set to a cylinder, and apply a mirror modifier on the cylinder with the box object set as the mirror object

Comment: could you, please, provide some screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

icosphere cut by a cyclinder

[image]

cylinder is mirrored along icosphere

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use the *Mesh > Symmetrize* tool (choose the axis in the *Operator* box on the bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]

Once done, you'll need to make sure that you don't have ripped edges like this:

[image]

To fix that, add some edge loops with the knife tool and merge the vertices:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the point of adding extra edges? And why should they be loops?

Comment: I've edited my answer, once you've symmetrized you need to make sure that you have a good topology, I hope it's clear